# catch api 404 response with Angular2 http

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, response, angular

I have api which returns 400 or 404 errors if failed.

When I run the http.get method, it does not catch the error on subscribe and throws error.

```
Http.get(`api/path/here`).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
```

Following is the error I get

[image]

Comment: take a look in the `network` tab for `status code` and in the preview tab for error information

Comment: @PardeepJain status code is 400 that whats the api returns, if user object is not found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.subscribe(res=>{
    this.data=res;
    console.log('bye');
 },
 (err)=>console.log(err),
 ()=>console.log("Done")
 );
```

Try out this way.

Answer (score 11):

You could also use the `catch` operator

```
http.get(`api/path/here`)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(
        err => {
          // handle errors
        })
    .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data)
    );
```

Comment: Does the "catch" have any benefit over utilizing the "onError" method on the subscribe operator itself?  If I simply include an "onError" method implementation, is there a chance I could have uncaught exceptions possibly caused by my "map" operator?  Thanks!