# Angular 2 - Http client rejects promise when status code is 404

Tags: javascript, angular

I recently started using Angular 2 and quickly discovered that when utilizing the HTTP client that a return code of 404 from the server ends up rejecting the promise.

Here's the code I have in my service:

```
  export class CalculatorService {

  private _serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCode(request: CalculatorRequest) {
    return this.http.post(this._serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(request), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as CalculatorResponse)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error): Promise<any> {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server Error : Service Unavailable';

    if (errMsg != null) {
      return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, instead of resolving the promise, my handleError method is called as the 404 causes a rejection.

Is there a straightforward way to resolve a request with a return code of 404?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry this may not be the answer you are looking for, however have you considered using observables? They allow for a better (in my opinion) way of handling errors (and responses)

Comment: No worries!  I am very new at utilizing Angular 2 and have only briefly looked at Observables.  I will definitely be looking into them further as they appear to be extremely powerful.

Comment: I would offer an observable solution, however people returning to this question in the future will be looking for a way to do it with promises. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520669/6894075) deals with how to do this in an observable if you want to switch and do it that way!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Yes, it causes a rejection. And yes, it should can be handled in catch - like any other expected error. If only thing you do in catch is rejection, this will result in rejected promise when there's http error.